# Sql Query for inserting data

Tags: sql, insert

I have to insert the record in existing  table, closing the status basically so, if nothing is there to work on that record then i have to insert one more line keeping all column data same, but adding in status column as "closed".

I have a temporary table in which I have latest records so in every record with order id number, I have to insert one more line of each order id, and order status column closed.

Could you please help me, how can I keep all column values same and add few columns values changed value and insert it.

I am trying an insert query. insert into table (select )

```
SELECT 
    txt_order_id, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY txt_order_id ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC) 'rank',
    txt_order_enc_id, create_timestamp, txt_actstatus, txt_act_text_display,  
    txt_action
INTO   
    #t1
FROM
    order_management_data_
WHERE
    txt_order_id IN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), seq_no) 
                     FROM order_ (nolock)
                     WHERE actstatus = 'ordered'
                       AND actclass IN ('REFR')
                       AND create_timestamp <= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()))
                       -- AND encounterdate < '20191003')

--temporary table is ready.

select p.med_rec_nbr, * 
from #t1 t
inner join patient_encounter pe on pe.enc_id = t.txt_order_enc_id
inner join patient p on pe.person_id = p.person_id
where txt_actstatus in ('appointment declined', 'No Longer Needed')
  and rank = 1
order by p.med_rec_nbr
```

I want to insert the record and adding the status as closed.

Comment: Does the SELECT work stand-alone?

Comment: Reading tips: [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: no actually that select is only to collect the latest order status and taking it into temporary table, so now i know the records exist, so i need to insert one more record and adding status closed for each order id.

Comment: insert into order_management_data_
select * from #t1.. i am trying this. but i need to change the values of two columns. how can i do that